# how to move lower z-level element below transparent png

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following website that lets me scale an image and crop it and stuff.  You can drag and pan the image around:

http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/crop_move.html

I wanted to try to implement a mask over the top, which I did here:

http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/crop_mask1.html

Problem is that because the mask.png covers the whole butterfly.img, I can't drag and pan the image anymore.  I'm trying to think of a way that I can put the mask over the top, but still be able to move the source image around.

Does anybody have some ideas, thoughts, or suggestions of stuff I can look into?

Comment: wanted to add this link I found for future users: http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pointer-events: none;` for overlayed image but it wont work for all browsers, i guess.

```
#overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I have tested it myself and it worked. Can you show your code?